# Awesome widget formatted print

Tags: awesome

I have the following widget definition:

```
netwidget = widget({ type = "textbox" })
vicious.register(netwidget, vicious.widgets.net, '<span color="#CC9393">${p17p1 down_kb}</span> <span color="#7F9F7F">${p17p1 up_kb}</span>', 3)
```

Which prints network usage on /dev/p17p1.

How can I make those numbers be a fixed width say, `%3.2f` or something?